# How do you cite when using a reference twice within the body of a composition but not necessarily in the same paragraph?

Tags: creative-writing

How do you cite when using a reference twice within the body of a composition but not necessarily in the same paragraph?

Comment: Some examples would be nice.

Comment: Where are you putting your bibliography? or are you using footnotes or running text citations?

Comment: Welcome to Writers.  You tagged this [tag:creative-writing] but I'm not used to creative writing calling for citations.  What kind of writing are you doing?  (Maybe you meant to tag it something else, like essay or technical-writing or academic-writing?)  Also, do you follow a particular style guide?  You can [edit] your question to add information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The correct citation depends on your style guide.

In **APA** and **MLA**, you must cite every repetition of each source in the same way, no matter how close or far they appear. In some cases, the same reference may appear in subsequent sentences or even within the same sentence. **Neither APA nor MLA allow the use of "ibid." or "op.cit.".** Example (in APA format):

> In their study, Paul and Pope (2004) have found that citing sources is a pain. They used the APA Manual to style their citations. Johnson (2003) on the other hand found citing to be a joy. In his study he used MLA. But using APA is recommended in certain fields (Paul & Pope, 2004). Many studies also found some other stuff (Paul & Pope, 2004; Johnson, 2003; Whoever, 1783).

Note how I referred to a source using a pronoun in a subsequent sentence ("They used ...") and thereby avoided having to repeat the citation. If there is no referring pronoun, the source must be repeated. Example:

> In their study, Paul and Pope (2004) have found that citing sources is a pain. Although using APA is recommended in certain fields (Paul & Pope, 2004), other fields recommend MLA (Paul & Pope, 2004), Chicago (Johnson, 2003), or not to cite at all (Whoever, 1783).

Note how in the last list-style sentence, the same source is given twice, once for each list item.

The guiding rule is that it must be unmistakeably clear where each quotation or paraphrase in your text comes from. In the following example it is unclear, what the source for the recommendation to use MLA is:

> Although using APA is recommended in certain fields (Paul & Pope, 2004), other fields recommend MLA, Chicago (Johnson, 2003), or not to cite at all (Whoever, 1783).

Answer (score 0):

If you're citing the exact same source, you can use "Ibid." (Ibid., pp. 20)

But normally, you just cite like normal:

"Quote One" (Smith, pp. 15).

"Quote Two" (Smith, pp. 15).

"Quote Three" (Smith, pp. 18).

Just make sure you're using the correct style (in-text vs footnotes, APA vs MLA, etc). There are multiple citation generators on the web.

Comment: Better yet, use a reference manager like EndNote, Zotero, or Mendeley to easily keep track of your references and cite them throughout your writing as needed. Those all have plug-ins that work with Word/OpenOffice.

Comment: The use of "ibid" is discouraged nowadays.